# Problem with mapping structure from C to Java using Java Native Access

Tags: java, jna

I have the following extract of C header from the project that I would like to map to Java using JNA:

```c
...

typedef size_t ObjectHandle;

typedef const char *FfiStr;

typedef struct FfiList_FfiStr {
  size_t count;
  const FfiStr *data;
} FfiList_FfiStr;

typedef struct FfiList_FfiStr FfiStrList;

int create_schema(FfiStr schema_name,
                  FfiStr schema_version,
                  FfiStr issuer_id,
                  FfiStrList attr_names,
                  ObjectHandle *result_p);
...
```

I cannot find the right mapping to Java for the FfiStr and FfiStrList types.

Here is the mapping I have tried in Java:

```java
public interface CredLibrary extends Library {
    CredLibrary INSTANCE = (CredLibrary) Native.load("credlibrary", CredLibrary.class);

    public class FfiStr extends Structure {
        public class ByReference extends FfiStr implements Structure.ByReference {};
        public String FfiStr;

        public FfiStr(){
            FfiStr= new String();
        }

        public FfiStr(String s) {
            FfiStr = new String(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("FfiStr");
        }
    }

    public class FfiList_FfiStr extends Structure{
        public Size_t count;
        public FfiStr.ByReference[] data;

        public FfiList_FfiStr(String[] attr){
            super();
            count = new Size_t(attr.length);
            data= new FfiStr.ByReference[attr.length];
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("count", "data");
        }
    }

    int create_link_secret(PointerByReference link_secret_p);
    int generate_nonce(PointerByReference nonce_p);
    int create_schema(FfiStr schema_name, FfiStr schema_version, FfiStr issuer_id,FfiList_FfiStr attr_names, IntByReference result_p);

}
```

The first create_link_secret and generate_nonce functions work fine, create_schema doesn't work.

And here is the test I have tried:

```java
CredLibrary.FfiStr schema_name= new CredLibrary.FfiStr("test");
CredLibrary.FfiStr schema_version = new CredLibrary.FfiStr("v1");
CredLibrary.FfiStr issuer_id =new CredLibrary.FfiStr( "123");


CredLibrary.FfiList_FfiStr attrib = new CredLibrary.FfiList_FfiStr(attr);
IntByReference pref3= new IntByReference();
int c= lib.anoncreds_create_schema(schema_name,schema_version,issuer_id,attrib,pref3);
int p3 =pref3.getValue();

Log.i("TEST","Value of the schema created:"+String.valueOf(c));
```

To be more precise create_schema outputs 1 which is the ErrorCode value for input value related problems. So this probably means that my mapping between structures from C to Java is not correct. So I am probably doing something wrong in the Java mapping code.

Would it be possible to indicate what I do wrong?

I was thinking maybe FfiStr is wrong since the Java FfiStr has an attribute while the C doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

C `const char *` maps to Java `String`.  JNA has mappings for `size_t` depending on your operating system.

You generally don't need, and should not add the `ByReference` tags. These add another level of pointer indirection which is usually wrong.  Inline in structures you don't want the pointer, and JNA defaults to ByValue.  As function/method arguments you usually do want the pointer, and JNA defaults to ByReference here.

You do have an array of Strings in your Structure, but JNA requires the array length to be declared when initialized. This works if you're declaring it on the Java side but requires some extra steps to override `read()` on the structure if reading it from the native side.

You can just delete your `FfiStr` structure and use `String` for that mapping.  You could wrap it inside a Structure (for type safety, for example), but do so without using `ByReference` on it since the `String` mapping already includes the pointer.

For your second structure, it's a bit more complicated.  When declaring a Structure, JNA allocates the memory for it, so it needs to know the size of the array.  So you need to give data a nonzero initialization and then overwrite the value and re-allocate memory in the constructor.

In addition, the memory allocated for a Structure must be contiguous native memory. Declaring an array in Java with primitives allocates native memory, but for Strings and other Objects it doesn't.  Nested structure arrays can be created with contiguous memory with `toArray()` (if you chose to map `FfiStr` as a structure).

You can always just map the String array argument to a `Pointer` since that's actually what's happening on the native side; but that also requires you to handle allocating the memory and writing the string array yourself.

For String Arrays, JNA provides a [`StringArray`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.13.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/StringArray.html) class which handles all the contiguous memory allocation.  Note there are multiple constructors to allow for Windows (UTF-16 wide strings) vs. *nix-based implementations. Use the appropriate one for your OS (or provide both if you're cross-platform).

While `StringArray` handles the contiguous allocation, you need to map its `Pointer` superclass inside the `Structure`.

Some other notes:

- you haven't indicated how you have mapped `Size_t` but it is generally pointer-sized.  If you're on a 64-bit operating system it's going to be 8 bytes.  JNA has `size_t` mappings you can use.
- The method `create_schema` argument `FfiList_FfiStr attr_names` does not include the `*` indicating a by-reference value, indicating the structure should be passed on the stack by value.  So you need to add a `ByValue` tag to your structure and use it in the method call.

```java
@FieldOrder ({"count", "data"})
public class FfiList_FfiStr extends Structure{

    public class ByValue extends FfiList_FfiStr implements Structure.ByValue {};

    public size_t count; // use JNA's size_t
    public Pointer data;

    public FfiList_FfiStr(String[] attr){
        count = new Size_t(attr.length);
        data = new StringArray(attr);
    }
}
```

and

```java
int create_schema(
   String schema_name,
   String schema_version,
   String issuer_id,
   FfiList_FfiStr.ByValue attr_names,
   size_t.ByReference result_p 
);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. I have implemented your advices. Now I use String instead of FfiStr. But now I receive this error : 
                                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure field "data" was declared as class [Ljava.lang.String;, which is not supported within a Structure

 it says that it is illegal to use String[] inside a Structure ? But why would it be illegal to use such a type inside a Structure ?

Comment: @zerokerim Oops,  I'll update my answer...  I guess I shouldn't have gone from memory.  The TLDR is that structure memory needs to be contiguous.  Declaring an array of objects in Java doesn't always mean they have contiguous native memory.  JNA does that for primitives but not for Strings.  However, this is common enough that JNA has a `StringArray` class for this purpose.

Comment: Hello, thank you again very much for your help. Unfortunately, it seems that even with StringArray I receive the same error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure field "data" was declared as class com.sun.jna.StringArray, which is not supported within a Structure.
Maybe a better solution would to approach the problem with Pointers. What would you think about this ?

Comment: @Zerokerim apologies agin... `StringArray` does extend `Memory` so it is indeed a `Pointer` under-the-hood.  Map the Structure type as a `Pointer` but assign the `StringArray` to it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer and sorry for my late reply. I have tried as you said to use a Pointer but by assigning the StringArray to it in the constructor. And I no longer receive IllegalArgumentException. But I do receive another error I do not understand :
 First I receive the following warning : malloc(3184123619830656) failed: returning null pointer
and then I receive the error : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4731
I don't understand why but malloc seems to fail when I assign a StringArray to the Pointer.

Comment: 3184123619830656 bytes is 3 Petabytes, an incredibly large amount of memory that you're trying (and failing) to allocate.  There are two allocations involved with the string array, one for an array of pointers (array size plus one) and one for each of the strings (done separately).  Java arrays are limited to 32 bits so this can't be the length; somhow you have an incredibly large string in your array.  Where is the data coming from?